# How many estimated percentage of my weight that I lift while doing elevated push ups

Tags: exercise, push-ups

Question No. 1:

How many estimated **percentage of my weight** that I lift while doing elevated push ups with my feet on my unstable bed about 60cm from the floor (so I also keep my balance work here) ?

I can do it 10 reps, after I usually do 60 - 100 reps classic push ups and 10 deep push ups.

My weight is 76kg. It can vary from 73 - 76kg, I'll continue my "strict" diet lifestyle again in September 2011.

[Related Weight thread for Classic Push ups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/what-is-the-effective-weight-when-doing-push-ups)

This is the pic I stole from [baseops](http://www.baseops.net/basictraining/pushups.html), I believe for my case, my feet is 15-20cm higher than that.

[image: elevated push ups]

Question No. 2:

I can only do 2 reps of **not perfect** hand stand push ups so far, I'm not 180 degree upside down, maybe about 20 - 30 degree to be completely upside down. Is it true that I lift my total body weight (76kg) while doing it ?

I really feel something GOOD on my shoulders' muscle for both of these kinds of push ups. Specially for hand stand push ups, about 2 - 5 minutes after that workout, I kinda feel refresher. I wonder if that happened because my blood flowing to my head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1: They physics is somewhat tricky since so much depends on the exact angle and the distribution of weight on your body. A better approach is just to measure by putting a scale under your hands and do a diamond push-up (so both your hands fit on the scale). See what the scale reads at the bottom of the push-up versus the top. Take the average and you're done.

Answer 2:
Unless you're going perfectly up and down, you're not lifting the full mass.

Comment: +1 for Answer 1, I'll get back to update this thread/comment once I'm done with the scale. Thanks!